# Unable to deploy an android application with RADStudio 11.3

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

I have just migrated my RadStudio from 11.2 to 11.3 and when I try to make an android application it is impossible to deploy it on my phone.
Here are the error messages:

```
c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176 Impossible d'exécuter '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-22.0.47991.2819\build-tools\32.0.0\lib\apksigner.jar" sign --ks "C:\Users\remie\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\22.0\debug.keystore" --ks-pass pass:android --ks-key-alias "androiddebugkey" --key-pass pass:android "D:\Projets\Delphi\test\Android\Debug\Project1\bin\Project1.apk"' (erreur 2)
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176 Failed to load signer "signer #1"
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176 java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:225)
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadKeyStoreFromFile(SignerParams.java:362)
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCertsFromKeyStore(SignerParams.java:248)
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCerts(SignerParams.java:181)
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.getSignerConfig(ApkSignerTool.java:405)
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:324)
      c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:88)

Génération de la cible "\_AndroidSign" terminée dans le projet "Project1.dproj" -- ÉCHEC.
Génération du projet "Project1.dproj" terminée -- ÉCHEC.
ÉCHEC de la build.
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176 Impossible d'exécuter '"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_60\\bin\\java.exe" -jar "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\22.0\\CatalogRepository\\AndroidSDK-2525-22.0.47991.2819\\build-tools\\32.0.0\\lib\\apksigner.jar" sign --ks "C:\\Users\\remie\\AppData\\Roaming\\Embarcadero\\BDS\\22.0\\debug.keystore" --ks-pass pass:android --ks-key-alias "androiddebugkey" --key-pass pass:android "D:\\Projets\\Delphi\\test\\Android\\Debug\\Project1\\bin\\Project1.apk"' (erreur 2)
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176 Failed to load signer "signer #1"
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176 java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:225)
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadKeyStoreFromFile(SignerParams.java:362)
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCertsFromKeyStore(SignerParams.java:248)
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCerts(SignerParams.java:181)
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.getSignerConfig(ApkSignerTool.java:405)
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:324)
c:\\program files (x86)\\embarcadero\\studio\\22.0\\bin\\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(1111,5): error : Erreur : E7176    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:88)
0 Avertissement(s)
14 Erreur(s)
Temps écoulé 00:00:08.41
```

I have checked my configuration and it seems ok

---

Yes I have already checked the paths before this post and they are ok

Message translation:

```
Impossible d'exécuter = impossible to execute
Erreur = Error
Génération de la cible = Target generation
ÉCHEC= Failure
Génération du projet = Project generation
```

I have tried Temurin OpenJDK and the result is the same

Comment: Can you translate the French error messages?

Comment: It's possibly because you are using the Oracle JDK. Delphi 11.x requires the use of the Temurin OpenJDK. In Delphi, use Tools | Manage Platforms, select the Additional Options tab, select the OpenJDK (last item) and click Apply. Once installed, configure the Java settings for the Android SDK to use this JDK instead

Answer (score 1):

This error show some path that are needed to sign the application:

- **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe**
  **C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-22.0.47991.2819\build-tools\32.0.0\lib\apksigner.jar**

Go to your SDK/NDK/Java configuration and test if is correct and if this files (java.exe, apksigner.exe) exists in this location.

[image]

[image]